# ¿Como hago para transormar un archivo JSON (anidado) a CSV en Pandas?

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

Hola estoy queriendo leer tres archivos JSON en python y los quiero transformar a csv pero no se como hacerlo, alguien sabe como?, gracias.

Comment: Intentaste con algún código? O miraste en alguna parte como podrías hacer? Si es así, te recomiendo demostrar que hiciste algo por tu cuenta, ya que preguntas que no muestran ningún esfuerzo, no suelen ser bien recibidas

Comment: si, hice esto para ver en la impresion si tenia un error el json . import json

try:
    json_data = json.loads(json_data) 
    aus_reviews = pd.json_normalize(json_data)  en un DataFrame
except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
    print(f"Error de formato JSON: {e}")    y en la impresion me tiro esto: Error de formato JSON: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)

Comment: Parece que tu json tiene algo que no permite al parser interpretarlo. No pareciera ser un error de pandas. Podrías editar la pregunta y agregar una muestra del json para ver mejor que sucede y el código que me mostraste en la pregunta así queda mas ordenada la publicación por favor?

Comment: Agregar una muestra del archivo que reproduzca el problema es esencial como comenta Dante.Si es de dominio publico agrega un enlace al recurso, si no crea un ejemplo mínimo que reproduzca el problema y agregalo a la pregunta.Tiene pinta de que el archivo no es un archivo jsonlines. **JSONLines espera un archivo/iterable en el que cada fila/item represente un JSON completo y valido**.Si tu archivo es un archivo JSON normal,JSONLines no es la biblioteca adecuada, si es un archivo jsonlines, algo hay mal aparentemente con la estructura del archivo,pero sin tener acceso al mismo es difícil ayudar.

Answer (score 0):

He tratado de hacer una funcion para poder leer mi archivo JSON y convertirlo a CSV, pero a la hora de ejecutar me tira el error siguiente: "voy a colocar el codigo y luego el error"

```
import pandas as pd
import jsonlines


input_json_file = 'australian_user_reviews.json'
```

output_csv_file = 'aus_reviews.csv'

def json_to_csv(input_file, output_file):
with jsonlines.open(input_file) as reader:
data = [item for item in reader]

```
df_aus = pd.json_normalize(data)
df_aus.to_csv(output_file, index=False)
```

json_to_csv(input_json_file, output_csv_file)

ERROR: InvalidLineError: line contains invalid json: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1) (line 1)

Comment: Esta sería la sección de respuestas. Para agregar esta información a tu pregunta, editala. El botón editar está abajo de la pregunta y las etiquetas. Además, tengo la hipotesis de que el error en cuestión está en el json que tratas de cargar. Por eso te pedí una muestra.

Comment: hola danta muchas gracias, tenias razon con mis JSON tenia problemas con el encoding y ya he encontrado la solucion,. gracias.